# Missing Header in HTTP Response due to CORS

Tags: cors, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using an `embedded jetty` via maven with version `<jetty.version>9.4.19.v20190610</jetty.version>`

I use a `CORS` Filter as follows:

```java
        FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(CrossOriginFilter.class);
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS_HEADER, "*");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS_HEADER, "true");
        holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM,
                "Access-Control-Request-Method,x-csrftoken,ClientKey,If-None-Match,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Prefer,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Accept,Origin,X-Requested-With,Pragma,Refer,Referer,User-Agent,Host,Connection,Cache-Control,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Content-Length,sec-fetch-mode,sec-fetch-site");
        holder.setName("cross-origin");


        staticServletHandler.addFilter(holder, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
```

I am able to query the `REST` endpoint which is hosted by jetty from any server without a `CORS` error. I am using the following `JS` (with `jquery`) code for accessing the endpoint (i am running the code in `chrome`):

```js
$.ajax({
          type:'Get',
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          url: myurl,
          success:((data,textstatus,request)=>{
            this.etag=request.getResponseHeader('E-Tag'); //null if JS is executed on another server
          }),
      });
```

If I host the `JS` code on the `jetty` I am additionally able to access the E-Tag, if I host the code on another server I **GET THE DATA but NOT THE E-TAG.** So if the JS Code is located on the same Server as the endpoint then I get the response header. If it is located on a different Server the headers are removed. Hence, I guess that this is a CORS error ( i dont get an error). **How do I have to configure the jetty that it works for remote request?**

Additional Information: I create e-tag header on jetty as follows:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(status).header("E-Tag","abc").build();
```

**EDIT:**
I added the following line:

```
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS_HEADER, "Content-Length, X-Kuma-Revision, E-Tag");
```

but the E-Tag header is still missing. The server definitely adds the header to the response as the following screenshot of `Postman` shows.

[image]

Comment: Confusing question.  Your question indicates that it works for Jetty, then you ask how to make it work for Jetty??

Comment: I am able to make a request but i don't get the header if the JS is hosted on another Server

Comment: Thx for your Feedback, I tried to clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Requests from another server to access the headers,  `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header needs to be sent along with the response. The value of the header should be comma separated list of the header names that you want to be exposed.

Example: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-Kuma-Revision`

Refer to the [Mozilla Developer link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) for more information and clarity.

Implementation: Add the following init parameter:

```
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.EXPOSED_HEADERS_PARAM, "Content-Length, X-Kuma-Revision, E-Tag");
```

Comment: The implementation is not proper as per your edit. You need to add parameter "EXPOSED_HEADERS_PARAM" similar to "ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM". Refer to my edited answer

Comment: CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS_HEADER is a constant which has the value "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" --> so my implementation seems to be identical to yours... or do I oversee something?

Comment: Please add the line: `holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.EXPOSED_HEADERS_PARAM, "Content-Length, X-Kuma-Revision, E-Tag");`


Not CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS_HEADER